# How to do this operation in numPy?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have an array X of 3D coords of N points (N*3) and want to calculate the eukledian distance between each pair of points.

I can do this by iterating over X and comparing them with the threshold.

```
coords = array([v.xyz for v in vertices])
for vertice in vertices:
    tests = np.sum(array(coords - vertice.xyz) ** 2, 1) < threshold
    closest = [v for v, t in zip(vertices, tests) if t]
```

Is this possible to do in one operation? I recall linear algebra from 10 years ago and can't find a way to do this.

Probably this should be a 3D array (point a, point b, axis) and then summed by `axis` dimension.

**edit:** found the solution myself, but it doesn't work on big datasets.

```
    coords = array([v.xyz for v in vertices])
    big = np.repeat(array([coords]), len(coords), 0)
    big_same = np.swapaxes(big, 0, 1)
    tests = np.sum((big - big_same) ** 2, 0) < thr_square

    for v, test_vector in zip(vertices, tests):
        v.closest = self.filter(vertices, test_vector)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`scipy.spatial.distance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html). If `X` is an `n`×3 array of points, you can get an `n`×`n` distance matrix from

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
D = distance.squareform(distance.pdist(X))
```

Then, the closest to point `i` is the point with index

```
np.argsort(D[i])[1]
```

(The `[1]` skips over the value in the diagonal, which will be returned first.)

Comment: @culebrón: never mind my previous comment (now deleted). The problem at that scale is memory; you're going to need GBs for the distance matrix. However, if you don't use `scipy.spatial.distance`, the problem is going to be CPU time. What exactly do you need to do with the distances?

Comment: I need to find the points within a threshold from each one, to cluster them.

Comment: Maybe the [`cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) function is interesting too, then.

Comment: I'll try. I tested scipy-cluster, it worked fine on very simple data (10 points), but on a small test file (1K points) it already failed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @culebrón: for clustering, be sure to also check out [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.  If you're computing the Euclidean distance between each pair of points in an N-point space, it would make sense to me to represent the results as a look-up matrix.  So for N points, you'd get an NxN symmetric matrix.  Element (3, 5) would represent the distance between points 3 and 5, whereas element (2, 2) would be the distance between point 2 and itself (zero).  This is how I would do it for random points:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5 

coords = np.array([np.random.rand(3) for _ in range(N)])
dist = np.zeros((N, N)) 

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i, N): 
        dist[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(coords[i] - coords[j])
        dist[j, i] = dist[i, j]

print dist
```

Comment: This is not what I need, because I tested the algorithm with cProfile. linalg.norm is VERY slow. Cycles are very slow too. Bulk operations on np.arrays are times as fast.

Comment: What sort of bulk operations are you referring to?

Comment: `np.sum(array(coords - vertice.xyz) ** 2, 1) < threshold` for example. It calculates the square of euclidean distance and compares it to a threshold. The result is an array of Booleans, indicating which vertices of the list are closer than the threshold to the current.

Answer (score 0):

If xyz is the array with your coordinates, then the following code will compute the distance matrix (works fast till the moment when you have enough memory to store N^2 distances):

```
xyz = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,3))
distances = (sum([(xyzs[:,i][:,None]-xyzs[:,i][None,:])**2 for i in range(3)]))**.5
```